# PAM: how to pass UID to pam_exec for sshd

Tags: linux, ssh, login, pam

I would like to execute a script during a user login per ssh on CentOS 7 with PAM pam-1.1.8-23.el7.x86_64

Thus, I added a rule to sshd's pam module to execute a script

```
/etc/pam.d/sshd
...
session    required     pam_exec.so {debug,seteuid} /usr/local/bin/foo.sh
...
```

However, the script is always executed under root. Also no arguments are passed, i.e., `$@` is empty in the script's context.

I also tried to use `login` instead, but also without success. I would like to stick to sshd, as to avoid problems with services and constrain the script to true ssh logins.

Is it possible to run a script via pam_exec under the UID of a user logging in per ssh?

Answer (score 3):

According to the `pam_exec` man page:

> The child's environment is set to the current PAM environment list, as returned by
> `pam_getenvlist(3)` In addition, the following PAM items are exported as environment variables:
> `PAM_RHOST`, `PAM_RUSER`, `PAM_SERVICE`, `PAM_TTY`, `PAM_USER` and `PAM_TYPE`, which contains one of the
> module types: `account`, `auth`, `password`, `open_session` and `close_session`.

We can find the name of the user in the `PAM_USER` environment
variable, and we can use that to run a script under the appropriate
UID.

E.g., if I have this in my pam configuration:

```
auth required pam_exec.so /usr/local/bin/pam_exec_stage_1
```

And in `pam_exec_stage_1` I have:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec /usr/sbin/runuser -u $PAM_USER /usr/local/bin/pam_exec_stage_2
```

Then `/usr/local/bin/pam_exec_stage_2` will be run with the UID of
whichever user is logging in.

Answer (score 1):

the username is actually available in the `$PAM_USER` environment variable